# Decorator is not being called in other functions

Tags: decorator

It seems that the decorator (@need_to_login) is not working in my code because when I open the webpage it goes straight to the home page and not the log in page. this is the simple code below. if there are any visible mistakes please tell me. I am fairly new to this. thanks

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='nelliville'

def need_to_login(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to log in first')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' and request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            return 'Invalid credentials'    
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/')
@need_to_login
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/logout')
@need_to_login
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i cant comment since i dont have enough reputation as im new to stack overflow.
try removing the `@wraps(f)` in your `need_to_login(f)`

Comment: I did this and it worked. I would like to ask why because i thought the wrap decorater is important since we will use the need_to_login decorator as a second decorater in the other function(home function). Thanks

Comment: @NelsonNN I dont think its really necessary to put that, according to this tutorial: [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python)